# Regex: How to introduce a non-greedy operator right before a negative lookahead

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to specify a non-greedy operator for a character that comes right before a negative lookahead. Nevertheless, when I specify the non-greedy operator, the word is captured even if the pattern present in the negative lookahead appears in the string.

The example is [here](https://regex101.com/r/VvTVMo/1)

```
pattern = "\bcuerpos?(?!\W*de\sseguridad)"

strings = ["el cuerpo", "cuerpo a cuerpo", 
           "fuerzas y cuerpos de seguridad", "fuerzas y cuerpo de seguridad"]
```

I want this patter not to match the third or the fourth strings, but it does capture the third one. Why does the non-greedy operator erase the negative lookahead functionality here and how would you solve this?

Comment: Question: Can 'cuerpo' or 'cuerpos' be part of a larger string? You currently have no boundaries around the substring meaning it can be part of a larger substring, e.g.: 'blahcueroposblah'.

Comment: Good point, I have a larger dictionary so I am assuming that before all words I specify a word boundary (but not at the end). Afterwards, the word boundary is implicit with `\W`. Let me modify the question to include the first word boundary

Comment: It's not implicit as long as you use `\W*` in a negative lookahead though. You need to be explicit after the match with another word-boundary.

Comment: You are right. I was thinking about the boundary as the words that would appear between the first substring “cuerpos?” and the negative lookahead string (which are indeed eliminated with `W*`), but I had not noticed that this did not include the remaining letters in the `cuerpo\w+` substring. For this case, I would not worry about the second word boundary, since I am matching AI transcripts, which can be messy (with words like `cuerposs` appearing). I would need to write \bcuerpos?(?!\W*de\sseguridad)\b` in order for it to avoid capturing `cuerpo de seguridad` and `cuerpos de seguridad.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can still get false positives in two ways:

- A line like `cuerpo a cuerpo de seguridad` contains 'cuerpo' without what should be negated, yet it's also present in the form you'd like to exclude;
- You currently are not using any boundary at the end of 'cuerpo', meaning it could be part of 'cuerpoblah'.

To counter both the above and the optional 's' and assuming you'd also want this to be case-insensitive I came up with:

```
import re

strings = ["el cuerpo", "cuerpo a cuerpo", 
           "fuerzas y cuerpos de seguridad", 
           "fuerzas y cuerpo de seguridad",
           "cuerpo a cuerpo de seguridad"]

p = re.compile(r'^(?!.*\bcuerpos?\b\W+de\sseguridad).*\bcuerpos?\b.*$', re.I)

new_strings = [s for s in strings if p.match(s)]

print(new_strings)
```

Prints:

```
['el cuerpo', 'cuerpo a cuerpo']
```

---

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/354yd8/1)

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(?!.*` - Open negative lookahead followed by 0+ characters upto;

  - `\bcuerpos?\b` - Match literally 'cuerpo' with an optional possessive (you could also remove the '+') 's' between word-boundaries;
  - `\W+de\sseguridad)` - Match 1+ non-word characters upto 'de', a single space before 'seguridad' and close the lookahead. **Note** This could even lead to a false negative since I don't know if you'd still want to allow a match when its 'seguridadblah`. A possible word-boundary could fix that too;
- `.*\bcuerpos?\b.` - Match 0+ characters upto the same pattern used for 'cuerpo' before and again 0+ characters;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

Comment: In my particular case, I am not too worried about word boundaries at the end of the word, since I am trying to match AI transcripts from audios, which can be quite messy (i.e., words like `cuerpoblah` could appear and I would still want to match them). Your first point on avoiding a match on “cuerpo a cuerpo de seguridad” is fair (even though it is unlikely for this sequence to appear on the transcripts). Hence, I understand that I can use your regex as: `r”^(?!.*\bcuerpos?\W+de\sseguridad).*\bcuerpos?.*$”` (i.e., eliminating the end-of-word word boundaries).

Answer (score 2):

You need to move `s?` inside the negative lookahead to make it:

```py
\bcuerpo(?!s?\W+de\sseguridad)
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VvTVMo/4)

Or if you want to match optional `s` as well then use:

```
\bcuerpo(?!s?\W+de\sseguridad)s?
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/VvTVMo/6)